# Deploy intranet application with SSL certificate

Tags: tls, web-application, http, intranet

My company has an intranet application build on the WAMP stack - Windows / Apache / MySQL / PHP. This application is installed on a server at each customer's site, and is accessed via LAN IP address. For example: `http://10.0.0.100/myapp.php` or `http://192.168.1.19/myapp.php`

How can I secure the web application so that it uses a valid SSL certificate? Issuing an SSL certificate from `mycompany.com` will not help because the web application is accessed from an arbitrary LAN IP address.

#### Self-signed SSL Certificate

It is possible to use self-signed SSL certificate as a workaround. That is not a long term solution, and I want to avoid users seeing this

[image: Invalid SSL certificate in Chrome]

Comment: You, the developers, can only give guidance to your customer's administration staff to properly configure the certificates for their users. It might be through a self-signed CA which signed the server certificate. Would it be satisfactory?

Comment: You need to create an [internal CA](https://blog.secureideas.com/2013/06/ssl-certificates-setting-up-and.html)

Comment: You could have a script that administrators run on the system straight after install. It would generate a CA then sign a certificate for the web application using its assigned internet hostname or domain name. Then the administrator distributes the CA cert to workstations for installation as a trusted root.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK setting the exception in each users browser is the only way to get rid of that message when using a self-signed certificate.
But: If your company has a wildcard certificate you could define a sub domain, that is just accessible in local net.

If your company doesn't have the wildcard certificate, you could still create the sub-domain, acquire a free SSL certificate (there are some certificate authorities lately offering ssl certificates for free) for the desired sub-domain for internal use.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
Create a internal CA (for each customer!), **add that CA root  to all clients** (using ActiveDirectory, for example) and create a Certificate for that service with that CA.

Option 2:
Create a Certificate for a subdomain of your Company domain **for each customer**. If you have supercoolapp, register `supercoolapp.ninja`. For customer A, get a certificate for `customerA.supercoolapp.ninja`. To get this certificate, you either need to be able to receive mail at `admin@supercoolapp.ninja` (or something similar), change the DNS of `supercoolapp.ninja` or host a small text/html file on a public webserver at `supercoolapp.ninja`.
You can do all of this without problems!

If possible, you then add `customerA.supercoolapp.ninja` into the local DNS of your customer A so it resolves to `10.0.0.100`.
If you can't do that, you can add this to your public DNS server!
This way, everyone on the internet looking for the IP of `customerA.supercoolapp.ninja` will also get the IP `10.0.0.100` but because that IP is private is not able to connect.

Comment: If customer has (all?) Windows-with-AD -- a big if -- they likely have Microsoft Certificate Services also, which already _is_ a locally trusted CA; if so just prepare a CSR for MCS to process and use the resulting cert. Or, accept a pkcs12 (key plus cert chain) already generated by Windows tools.